# How to count subfolders containing numbers?

Tags: command-line, directory

How can I use Terminal to count all direct subfolders in a directory that contain numbers?

So it shouldn't be counted recrusively.

Comment: What does "containing numbers" mean? Do you mean folders whose name is a number?Do you mean folders containing files whose names are numbers? Does that mean numbers only or would something like `file1` also count? How about extensions, should `.3.txt` be counted? And is having at least one such file enough for the folder to be counted or do you want to count only folders containing nothing but numerical file names? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: Please address the questions I asked too. We need to know what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

You can run the following command, that relies on `find` and `wc`, either from withing the directory inside which you wish to count the subdirectories (`find .`) or by replacing `find .` by the path to the directory you want to count subdirectories in (`find /path/to/directory`):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "*[0-9]*" -printf "." | wc -c
```

This command:

- finds directories only (`-type d`)
- searching only one level deep (`-maxdepth 1`)
- that contain at least one numerical digit anywhere in their name (`-name "*[0-9]*"`)
- then prints a `.` for any file found (`-printf "."`)
- and finally pipe (`|`) the result to `wc -c` to count the number of `.` (actually byte counts), which corresponds to the total number of directories found.

**References:**

- [`man find`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/find.1.html)
- [`man wc`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/wc.1.html)
- [Gilles Quénot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15663760/3140225) in [What is the best way to count "find" results?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15663607/3140225)

Answer (score 4):

To count *non hidden* subfolders in the current directory whose *names* contain at least one *digit*, you can use one of the following

In bash:

```
shopt -s nullglob
dirs=( *[[:digit:]]*/ )
printf '%d\n' "${#dirs[@]}"
```

If you omit the `nullglob`, it will return a count of 1 in the case that there are no matching subdirs. In POSIX sh (which doesn't have a nullglob equivalent) we need to check explicitly that we are not just counting the unmatched pattern:

```
set -- *[[:digit:]]*/
[ -d "$1" ] && printf '%d\n' "$#" || printf '0\n'
```

In either of the above, change `[[:digit:]]` to `[0123456789]` if you want to be sure to match Latin decimal digits only. To include hidden (dot) folders in the count in bash, you can set the `dotglob` option - in POSIX sh, you'd need to explicitly add `.*[[:digit:]]*/` I think.

In zsh (this one actually matches a numeric range rather than a single digit):

```
() { print -rl $# } *<->*(N/)
```

To include hidden folders in zsh, add the `D` (dotglob) qualifier.